# Как отследить ошибку в http.request

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть следующий код, который, в принципе, работает:

```
var request = http.request({
    hostname: host,
    path: "/mylink",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {Accept: "text/plain"}
}, function(response) {
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('hello!');
    });
});
request.end();
```

При выполнении функции консоль возвращает "Hello", но иногда этого не происходит.

При всём этом сама функция выполняется, например, если перед:

```
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('hello!');
});
```

вывести ещё какой-нибудь текст, то он в консоли отображаться будет, а вот 'data' - никак не хочет. Как отследить ошибку?

Answer (score 1):

Отследить ошибку можно стандартным способом:

```
response.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

То же самое можно повесить на `request`.
[Документация](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable)